# При нажатии на submit выдает ошибку

Tags: html, html5

Есть поле, которое я заполняю и при нажатии на submit выдает ошибку:

```
This field is required.
```

Вот код:

```
        <div id="geodir_<?php echo $prefix . 'address';?>_row"
         class="<?php if ($is_required) echo 'required_field';?> geodir_form_row clearfix gd-fieldset-details">
        <label>
            <?php _e($address_title, 'geodirectory'); ?>
            <?php if ($is_required) echo '<span>*</span>';?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" field_type="<?php echo $type;?>" name="<?php echo $prefix . 'address';?>"
               id="<?php echo $prefix . 'address';?>" class="geodir_textfield"
            <?php  /* value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($address)); ?>"/>   */ ?>
               value="<?php echo $getAddress->post_address; ?>"/>
        <span class="geodir_message_note"><?php _e($admin_desc, 'geodirectory');?></span>
        <?php if ($is_required) { ?>
            <span class="geodir_message_error"><?php _e($required_msg, 'geodirectory'); ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: WordPress тут ни при чем. Если поле имеет атрибут required, то оно будет вызывать такую ошибку. Может еще быть сделана проверка через js. Приведите результирующий код формы из инспектора браузера.

Comment: @KAGG Design, <input type="text" field_type="address" name="post_address"  id="post_address" class="geodir_textfield"              value=""/>  - здесь нет аттрибуту required

Comment: @KAGG Design, суть в том, что при нажатии на button(submit) данные не передаются в БД

Comment: 1. Код формы целиком надо поместить в вопрос. 2. У вас вопрос сформулирован иначе - ошибка при нажатии. При чем тут WP? Ни при чем - форма не работает, submit не происходит. Это проблема с html/js

Comment: @KAGG Design, убрал из вопроса слово "wordpress"

Comment: @KAGG Design, там валидация происходит же НЕ в html

Comment: Ну и не в php же! Пока html формы целиком не покажете, вам вряд ли кто поможет. Откуда сообщение-то берется? Покажите, как это выглядит, найдите, какой js повещен на форму. Я уже писал выше, что js может показывать сообщение. Скорее всего, показывается span class="geodir_message_error", который изначально скрыт через css. Показывает такой span js-код, выполняемый в браузере.

Comment: @KAGG Design, сейчас начну копать js. А форма целиком на 5000 строк почти...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67939/discussion-between--and-kagg-design).